# I want to set Push Notification Sound from Asset Folder ,Android

Tags: android, push-notification, assets

I have an .mp3 file in **asset** folder named "error.mp3" . i want set that sound along with the push notification , how can i do that , i have tried this code to do that

```
 Uri sound = Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/error.mp3");
 mBuilder.setSound(sound);
```

but its not working, when i use the default notification sound , it's working. i need some  help...

This is my  *BroadcastReceiver* class

```
public class Notificationmassage extends BroadcastReceiver {


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


    showNotification(context);

}

private void showNotification(Context context) {
    Log.i("notification", "visible");



    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            new Intent(context, MainActivity.class), 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic)
                    .setContentTitle("Radio Planet")
                    .setContentText("Explore music");
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);


    mBuilder.setVibrate(new long[] { 500, 500});


    //Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    //mBuilder.setSound(alarmSound);



   Uri sound = Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/error.mp3");
   mBuilder.setSound(sound);

    mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(2, mBuilder.build());


}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to put your `.mp3` files in raw folder instead of `assets`, sometimes it's not working so please  use like this

```
Uri path = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.test/" + R.raw.sample);
```

`com.example.test` // replace this with your package name

and then set

```
mBuilder.setSound(path);
```

Folder Structure

```
res/raw/test.mp3
```

Hope it will work for you. Enjoy Programming.

[image]

[image]

Comment: i got your answer when i was searching for the answer , but i am not seeing any folder named  raw, should i create a folder ??

Comment: Yes, you have to create raw folder. The raw folder must be inside the res folder, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: yes i created . now error.mp3 is inside raw folder , whats next ?

Comment: @JaisonJoseph now replace `Uri sound = Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/error.mp3")` with `Uri path = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.test/" + R.raw.sample);`

Comment: @JaisonJoseph `com.example.test` with your package name

Answer (score 0):

please put your `.mp3` file in `raw` directory and try below code

```
Uri sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.error);
```

Comment: i got your answer when i was searching for the answer , but i am not seeing any folder named raw, should i create a folder ??

Comment: yes you need to create raw folder in res/raw/error.mp3.

Comment: context.getPackageName()

Answer (score 0):

Put it in raw folder and use like below

```
    Uri uri=Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/raw/notification_sound.mp3");
```

Comment: instead of "/raw/notification_sound.mp3" i should put "/raw/error.mp3" right ?